# Тире, двоеточие или скобки?

Tags: пунктуация

Запуталась в поясняющих знаках... 
Что нужно в этом предложении перед словом "чтобы" - тире или двоеточие?

Под энергетической безопасностью понимается безопасность спроса и предложения(:) чтобы потребители получили уверенность в поставках, а поставщики – уверенность в спросе.

Другое предложение... в авторском варианте было со скобками, но мне хочется поставить тире или двоеточие...

Развитые страны теряют доминирующее положение в качестве покупателей энергоресурсов (на сегодня за ними треть потребления мирового производства угля и более половины мировой добычи нефти).

Answer (score 2):

Под энергетической безопасностью понимается безопасность спроса и предложения(а именно): чтобы потребители получили уверенность в поставках, а поставщики – уверенность в спросе. - БСП, второе предложение поясняет содержание первого.

Развитые страны теряют доминирующее положение в качестве покупателей энергоресурсов (на сегодня за ними треть потребления мирового производства угля и более половины мировой добычи нефти).Авторский вариант верен: вставная конструкция достаточно распространённая, скобки более уместны, однако можно поставить и точку,и запятую: предложения самостоятельны, самодостаточны, характеризуют одно явление, но с разных сторон. Двоеточие не совсем уместно, потому что во втором предложении нет причины или объяснения, в чём выражается уменьшение потребления электроэнергии,там пояснятся попутно, даны добавочные сведения к первому.

Comment: Т.е. двоеточие в первом предложении верно? Почему-то кажется корявым ставить его перед "чтобы"...

Comment: Или нужно добавить "а именно"? Я не поняла... :)

Comment: Двоеточие перед " чтобы" совершенно нормально. Нет никакой корявости. Добавлять "а именно" не нужно. Что касается второго предложения, то, действительно, они достаточны самостоятельны; тире обычно ставится когда вставная конструкция тесно связана с всем предложением. Как отметила Людмила, можно поставить точку с запятой.

Comment: Это по сути не СПП, потому что указывается не причина действия, выраженного сказуемым (ПОНИМАЕТСЯ, чтобы...), а разъясняется состав подлежащего (безопасность..., которая выражается в том, чтобы потребители получили...), это присловное придаточное, поясняющее смысл подлежащего, как бы самостоятельное предложение в БСП

Comment: Мне как раз показалась неясной структура предложения: на СПП не очень похоже, а наличие союзов не  позволяет считать, что это БСП. Поэтому лучше использовать вставную конструкцию, заключенную в скобки.

Answer (score 2):

1) "Под энергетической безопасностью понимается безопасность спроса и предложения: чтобы потребители получили уверенность в поставках, а поставщики – уверенность в спросе".

Можно вставить (только для проверки) "а именно", в устной речи присутствует  пауза, предупреждающая о последующем разъяснении.

В принципе с разъяснительной ролью может справиться и тире, но оно уже присутствует в неполном придаточном.

Постановка скобок также возможна, если автор считает, что пояснение можно отнести на второй план речи. Возможно, этот вариант даже лучше, чем двоеточие, так как структура предложения без вставной конструкции не очень ясна.

2) Во втором предложении лучше использовать скобки в связи с добавочным характером сообщения (числовая информация, поясняющая текст).

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

В СПП, кроме запятых, могут использоваться и другие знаки препинания (двоеточие,тире,точка с запятой),  которые считаются неосновными.
двоеточие ставится, если одно придаточное или ряд однородных придаточных поясняют содержание главного предложения, например:

Я опасаюсь одного: чтобы вся эта история не получила огласки.

Он почувствовал, что результат получился желаемый: что он тронут и она тронута.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

1.Первое предложение составлено наподобие "в огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька". В нем "понимается" и "чтобы" не согласуются. И спор бесполезен.
2.Во втором предложении можно поставить скобки, поскольку в них заключается дополнительное самостоятельное предложение, несущее информацию, а можно и точку с запятой. Просто запятая потребовала бы включения слов, связанных с сравнением с предыдущей ситуацией, вроде, "поскольку сегодня...только треть... угля и чуть более половины... нефти".